# How do I correctly add data from multiple endpoints called inside useEffect to the state object using React Hooks and Context API?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, react-context, use-effect

I am making calls to firestore inside the `fetchData` function and then adding the received data to state object but the problem is the global state is overwritten by the last api call as seen in my `console.log` output:

[image: console log output]

Here's my code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { db } from './firebase';

export const StateContext = React.createContext();

export function ContextController({ children }) {
    const intialState = {
        projectList: [],
        blogList: [],
        count: 0
    };

    const [state, setState] = useState(intialState);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    async function fetchData() {
        // get all projects
        db.collection('projects')
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
                let sorted = [];

                // loop through each object and push to sorted array
                data.forEach((item) => {
                    sorted.push(item.body);
                });
                // reverse sort the projects
                sorted.sort(
                    (a, b) => parseInt(b.project_id) - parseFloat(a.project_id)
                );
                setState({
                    ...state,
                    projectList: sorted
                });
            });

        // get all blogs
        db.collection('blog')
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
                setState({
                    ...state,
                    blogList: data
                });
            });
    }

    return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
            {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

How do I correctly add data from both endpoints to the state object so that I can access it anywhere in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is where you spread the old state into `setState` the state has gone stale. React does some performance enhancements around setState that will make code like this not work as expected.

One thing to try is using the setState callback.

```
setState((state) => ({
                ...state,
                projectList: sorted
            }));
```

Comment: Wow that works , that callback was definitely the issue. Thanks!